In VSEPR, why do lone pairs have stronger repulsion?
I've seen conflicting answers:

Lone pairs take up more space because there isn't another atom on the
other end. With a greater volume to move around in, they can repel
more.

Lone pairs are closer to the central atom, so they take up less
space, which the more centralized electrons create more repulsion.



This question is similar to: Why are lp-lp repulsions greater than bp-lp and bp-bp?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Strength of repulsion depends on charge density and distance. The repulsion between two charges equidistant from the nucleus diminishes, for a fixed angle, as their distance from the nucleus increases.
Non-bonding electrons closer to the nucleus increase the local charge density and thereby lateral repulsions. Bonding electrons are spread between bonded nuclei. Spreading charge density reduces lateral interactions.
Explanations used to justify VSEPR can be accepted as a useful way to remember how to apply the rules and may be loosely grounded in reality.

I'm really not sure you can classify VSEPR as semi-empiric. There is an argument for a rigorous theory, but there is also an argument for an empirical theory. What I don't think it is: a rigorous theory, simplified be empirical observations. But it's all difficult.

@Martin-マーチン I  use "semi-empirical" to mean not derived from first principles (QM). It is heuristic, implementing rules justified based on principles of basic electrostatics, Lewis structures, and Pauling hybridization, with enough wiggle room to explain many results reasonably. It is implemented as a form of decision tree so it is pretty coarse-grained.

I see your point, but I still don't think it's an appropriate choice. VSEPR doesn't use any empirical data, but that should be a characteristic. I agree it's coarse grained with limited predictive means and there is a lot of retro engineering. I still don't want it to be lumped together with methods that approximate based on measured (or calculated) date.

@Martin-マーチン Well, data was used in refining the model (which of course is true with any model). Although I have not seen this done you should be able to write a simulation that replaces atoms with point charges, fixes bond lengths, and implements a repulsive electrostatic potential to derive structures matching VSEPR predictions. VSEPR uses parameters (number of bonds and non-bonding electrons ie Lewis structure) obtained by examining experimental structures, unlike ab initio solution for a wavefunction. I did not mean that it is equivalent to AM1 or such.

Pauli's Exclusion Principle contributes to the stronger repulsion of lone pairs.
According to this principle, no two electrons in an atom can have the same set of quantum numbers. Lone pairs have a higher energy than bonding pairs, which means they occupy a higher energy orbital. This higher energy orbital has a larger radius, resulting in a stronger repulsive force between the lone pair and other electron pairs.

You are messing up the principles of quantum mechanics (quantum chemistry).

no not messing up concepts i tried to make the answer more justified by stating this
